# Populate Kendo DropDownList with array from selected value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rest, kendo-ui

Using javascript I want to populate a dropdownlist (DDL2) with certain data from a REST JSON endpoint based on the selected value of the DDL2.

This DDL2 selected value is triggered by previous DDL1 selection (I have that part working). For example if DDL1 selected value is "Town" then the selected value for DDL2 is: "SELECT towninfo FROM towns ORDER BY towninfo". It's a SQL query, currently. I have the option of replacing it with a comma-delimited array of towns (RALEIGH,CHARLOTTE,ASHEVILLE...), or I could replace it with a JSON string. I'm open for suggestions on that part.

**What I want to do** is populate DDL2 with the selected array. So when I select "Towns" in DDL1 then DDL2 populates with a list of towns. Thanks!

Comment: Are you really trying to populate the same dropdownlist(DDL2) upon its own selection? I think paragraph1 is saying that.

Comment: @binbsr yes. Or if there is an easier way of showing a dropdownlist when DDL1 has selected one of the values requiring DDL2 to be populated (and shown. By default, DDL2 is hidden and a textbox is shown). DDL1 has a JSON structure like so: `    [{"COLUMN_NAME":"Town","DATA_TYPE":"varchar","OPERAND":"=","DATATYPE":"TEXT","DOMAINQUERY":"SELECT towninfo FROM towns ORDER BY towninfo","CATEGORY":"Location"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"City","DATA_TYPE":"varchar","OPERAND":"=","DATATYPE":"TEXT","DOMAINQUERY":null,"CATEGORY":"Customer"},...] ` You notice that the "DOMAINQUERY" field is null in the second record.

Comment: Populating dropdown with its own selection is not a difficult part. Can you provide some code how you are binding this json (structure looks great though) to DDL1. Are you using server wrappers (C#) or GPL verion?

Comment: I'm binding to a C# REST server object extension endpoint using a KendoUI dataSource. My intent is to keep the 'towns' array/list dynamic. So my process has to start with a query from the SQL database and either push an array into the DOMAINQUERY field or expose in another way. One of the suggestions was to have the towns in a comma-delimited form in the DOMAINQUERY field. I have to do this for three more queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something simple as populating a second drop down based on the first one's selection, here is a quick and dirty sample...

http://jsbin.com/AHOpAJA/1/edit

If you want something a bit more complicated, here is another one using three dropdowns, that all bind from a service. http://jsbin.com/ihodoc/3/edit

Comment: The second dropdown is already populating based on the first dropdown selection. I'm trying to populate the second one with it's 'own selection' as @binbsr mentioned above. I'm open to how I could programmatically create the dropdown on the fly based on DDL1's selection too...